# Can't store todos to local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning JavaScript right now and one of the practice application I am doing is to make a to-do list to learn the basics. Right now I'm having a hard time saving my inputs onto the local storage. I look into the console and local storage of my browser and only see that a key "todos" is being created but no values are stored in it.

I was wondering if anyone can help. Please ignore the way I structured my coding. I am still learning. (I know there are better and more efficient ways to make a to-do list.)

My code:

```
<body>
<header class = "centerAlign ">to-do list </header>
    <div class = "divA centerAlign input-group container" style = "list-style-type:none">
    <input class = "form-inline input-lg" id="itemInput" "type="text" placeholder="add things to do"/>
    <button class = "addButt btn btn-lg">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </button>

    <ul class = "ulist1 container">
        <!--List items gets inserted here-->
    </ul>
</div>
<button class = "clearAll btn">Clear localStroage</button>

<script>
    getTodos();

    //press enter to submit
    $("input").on('keydown',function(e){
        if(e.keyCode ==13){
            $("<li>").attr("class","apples").html(itemInput.value).fadeIn().appendTo(".ulist1");
            $("<button>").attr("class","doneButt btn pull-left glyphicon glyphicon-ok").appendTo($(".apples").last());
            $("<button>").attr("class","delButt btn pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-trash").appendTo($(".apples").last());
            clearInput();
            saveTodos();
            }
    });

    //click the submit button
    $(".addButt").click(function(){
        $("<li>").attr("class","apples ").html(itemInput.value).fadeIn().appendTo(".ulist1");
        $("<button>").attr("class","doneButt btn pull-left glyphicon glyphicon-ok").appendTo($(".apples").last());
        $("<button>").attr("class","delButt btn pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-trash").appendTo($(".apples").last());
        clearInput();
        saveTodos()

    }); 

    //clears the input box for new text
    function clearInput(){
        itemInput.value = "";
    }

    //button to delete
    $(".ulist1").on("click", ".delButt", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).remove();});
    });

    //put a line through the text and undo that line
    $(".ulist1").on("click", ".doneButt", function(e) {
        $(this).parents("li").toggleClass('withline');
    });

    //save data localStorage
    $(".addButt").click(function(){
    saveTodos();
    });

    function saveTodos(){
    localStorage.setItem("todos", itemInput.value);
    }

    //get data from localStorage
    function getTodos(){
    localStorage.getItem("todos");
    }

</script>

<script>//delete localstroage
$(".clearAll").click(function() {
    window.localStorage.clear();
    location.reload();
    return false;
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Well you call `clearInput()` right before saving the value of the input so...

Comment: OMG THANK YOU!. hahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call your own clearInput() function before you call saveTodos(). This means you first clear your input field and then save the value of the (now empty) input field to your local storage.

Therefore, you will always have the key 'todos' with an empty String as its value.

To be able to save your last entered input in your desired localStorage variable you'd just need to move the saveTodos() call before the clearInput() call.

However your use case suggests that you surely want to save more than just the last entered input but several todos. To achieve that, you will have to either use a seperate key for every entry or story all entries as an array. As LocalStorage only supports String values, you would have to use something like [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: yes.I have changed it and it is storing the value now. But you are right, it is only storing one value at a time. how would i store several todos?

Comment: There are two ways to do that: 1) use a unique key for every entry. Todo+timestamp would be a possibility, using a counter would be another. 2) store a stringified object instead of a simple string. You would have something like var todosObj = {todos:["go shopping","call aunt nana"]}. When you store it, you would do it like this: localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todosObj)). When you load the page you would have to convert the String back to an Object like this: var todosObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"))

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps commenting out `clearInput();` before calling `saveTodos();` will solve your problem. :)